# Keycloak duplicated "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" causing cors error

Tags: http-headers, cors, keycloak

I'm having an issue using the keycloak-js adapter on a React front-end.

After login a duplicated 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the `/token` endpoint causes a CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.example.com/auth/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://example.com, *', but only one is allowed.

The response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Methods
```

Keycloak 9 is running in standalone mode behind an Nginx proxy on https://accounts.example.com.

The keycloak-js adapater configuration:

```
{
  "realm": myRealm,
  "url": https://accounts.example.com/auth,
  "clientId": myClientId,
  "enable_cors": true
}
```

I already tried multiple combinations for the client "Web Origins":

`https://example.com`, `*`, `+`, but I can't figure out why I got an extra Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: @EI capitán facing same issue and tried all ways like yours.. any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

We have discovered that our own proxy were writing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as well. That's why together with keycloak we got it twice.

Our devops team has fixed the code of our proxy and it works now.

Comment: Thanks for idea, for us it was the same. Devops gave us a link to access the service straightaway bypassing proxy-server -> and it worked.

Comment: Cool! I am very glad it helped! We have spent quite some time figuring that out (

Answer (score -5):

`*` is not valid value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for sites running on https.

Remove `*` from web origins client configuration in the Keycloak and configure all used web origin explicitly (no wildchars).

Here is MDN on [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers):

> The value "*" only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information). In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name "*" without special semantics. Note that the Authorization header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly.